# How to whitelist tags?

Tags: support

I don't want to keep adding tags to the ignored list.

Is there a way to hide everything in my frontpage and only whitelist certain tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the (fairly) recently introduced "Custom Question Lists" feature:

- On the Questions page, click the Filter button
- Add the tags you want to whitelist to the "Tagged with:" list
- Click the Save custom filter button and give it a name like "My Whitelist"
- Go back to the Questions page, click the "More" dropdown and select your custom filter

Comment: wow, this is pretty nice. thank you!